# VideoView using Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-videoview

I am using a Fragment and I want to play video inside it. I have an issue with the method `videoView.setOnCompletionListener(getActivity());` It says that the method setOnCompletionListener(MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener) in the type VideoView is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentActivity). Here is my code:

```
public class my_Fragment extends Fragment implements
    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, OnCompletionListener   {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);

      VideoView videoView = (VideoView)v.findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
      MediaController mc = new MediaController(getActivity());
      //videoView.setMediaController(mc);
      videoView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
      videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://com.my.package/raw/"+R.raw.myvideo);
      videoView.start();
      videoView.requestFocus();
      videoView.setOnCompletionListener(getActivity());

      mFlipper = ((ViewFlipper) v.findViewById(R.id.flipper));
      mFlipper.startFlipping();

      Spinner s = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mStrings);
      adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
      s.setAdapter(adapter);
      s.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

      return v;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I don´t understand very well, I have an ActionBarActivity an inside it the fragment of the code above

Comment: It has implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener

Comment: Cast it: `videoView.setOnCompletionListener((MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener) getActivity());`

Comment: I get an error in Log cat: Cannot be cast to android.media.MediaPlayer$OnCompletionListener, Im using appcompat if it helps you to know what is the issue

Comment: Well, that doesn't really make sense, and you'll have to post more code, but first, are you sure your listener isn't supposed to be the Fragment? You have it setup as an `OnCompletionListener`. That is, use `this` instead of `getActivity()`.

Comment: you are right, I have to use this instead getActivity(), sorry, I don't understand very well why . Thank you for your help and patience